# Флаг в руки и барабан на шею

Tags: этимология

Намедни, во время очередного совещания с иностранными партнерами, одна дама сгоряча вбросила фразу:

```
Флаг в руки - барабан на шею
```

имея в виду желание одного из иностранцев своими силами построить некий объект на бескрайних просторах Родины :)

Далее, нам пришлось долго и упорно объяснять значение данного выражения нашему заморскому партнеру. В ходе объяснений мне самому стало любопытно - а собственно, где корни данного выражения?

Есть версии?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://orator.ru/int_krylatye_frasy.html

В этом словаре утверждается:

**Флаг в руки**. *Ироничное побуждение к какому-нибудь действию. Обычно так говорят о каком-либо необдуманном поступке. Если вам нужны проблемы, то флаг вам в руки. Выражение связано с пионерской организацией и пионерскими лозунгами; часть ироничной поговорки: Флаг тебе в руки и барабан на шею.*

Но мне более близко такое мнение:

Выражение появилось во времена развития линейной тактики ведения сухопутных боев, когда знаменосцы и барабанщики, шедшие зачастую в первых рядах, подвергались несколько большему риску, чем рядовые солдаты. Кроме того, знаменосец и барабанщик были своего рода указателями, куда и как идти. При этом они были весьма заметными целями. 
Соответственно, смысл выражения считается примерно таким: шуруй-ка ты сам рисковать почем зря.

Пионеры же повторяли воинские ритуалы, но отношение к пионерским ритуалам во времена "застоя" более иронично, смысл выражения поменялся на насмешливый: уже никто не верит в "светлое будущее коммунизма", только пионеры всё с той же символикой, теперь это стало ироническим пожеланием «успеха» в безнадежном деле, может, кто-то вкладывал в слова  и  отношение к массовым демонстрациям советского времени с флагами и оркестрами. Пошло народное творчество и всякие насмешливые дополнения типа "перо в зад" и т.д.

Comment: Версия почти такая же как и у @behemothus, но в более логичном исполнении - спасибо!

Comment: Всё  бы хорошо, но ни знаменосцы, ни тем более барабанщики никогда не были в  "первых рядах". https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9B%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0 -википедия, картинки.

Comment: Флаги-то как раз у гренадер в первых рядах (на картинке) Знамя и флаги обычно рядом с командирами, а они разве в конце?В книге «Искусство войны» Макиавелли : «… при начальнике батальонов… находятся барабанщики и флейтисты… звуком трубы командующий укажет, должны ли войска стоять на месте, идти вперёд или отступать, надо ли стрелять артиллерии, а после труб ту же команду повторят барабаны…». Возросшая роль барабанщика на поле боя, как средство управления войсками, сделало его активной мишенью. Их гибель приводила к дезорганизации отряда, не меньше, чем смерть командира.

Comment: В любом случае быть барабанщиком достаточно опасно было. А в 19 веке у них была  яркая одежда, привлекала внимание.
http://koof.ru/library/1812-god-znamena-znamenostsy-i-muzykanty-frantsuzskoj-armii/

Comment: Я еще слышал вариант "флаг тебе в руки, барабан на шею и отряд фашистов навстречу".

Answer (score 1):

Правы обе стороны. Знание воинских традиций интеллигенцией и некоторое перенесение очевидных действий на построение пионерии, которое выглядело торжественно только в глазах приверженцев коммунистической идеологии и крайне комично в глазах тех, кто помнил Империю, существовало примерно с конца 60-х прошлого столетия. Многие забыли, что есть окончание фразы: "...и белые чулки". Панталоны времён 1812 года, а в советском прошлом - парадно-выходные гольфы. Я вела очень активно-вынужденный образ жизни, будучи в пионерии, воспитываясь в семье, помнящей и чтящей историю государства Российского. И это выражение звучало в мою бытность иронично-подстрекающе, а в 90-е - почти уничижительно: тогда ассоциативные ряды сводились к самому плохому от пионерии и самому пошлому от cheerleading и белым колготкам, которые были на проститутках Невского проспекта (наравне с чёрными, просто белые считались "элитными"). Как-то так. Вот.

Comment: *Как-то так. Вот.* - вот "как-то так" и не получается. Сначала формальный момент:  Что за "обе стороны", которые правы? В вопросе вообще нет никаких "сторон". Ну и по сути. У вас все очень идеологизировано,  а ответа толком не видно. Да и отсылки к собственному мнению и волспоминаниям сами по себе - плохой аргумент. ПС Про "белые чулки" ни разу не слышал.

Answer (score 0):

В армии, вестимо. 
Барабанщики и знаменосцы (а еще горнисты) всегда имели особый статус, в первую очередь во время боевых действий. 
Ну знамя - это понятно, оно и сейчас тот же статус имеет. 
А барабан и горн поднимали в атаку, с их  помощью давались команды (до появления современных средств связи, а частично и после - вплоть до второй мировой войны), даже строевая песня без такой музыки не обходилась (сейчас уже на марше такого, увы, не услышишь).

Да и само выражение частично заместилось другим, того же происхождения. "Вперед - и с песней!".

Правда, сейчас выражение это приобрело скорее иронический характер, с намеком не невыполнимость задуманного. Но это уже вторично.

Comment: Может я под впечатлением мультфильмов о Чебурашке, но мне эта фраза напоминает о пионерах - там был еще такой персонаж, который просил у крокодила Гены отбойный молоток при помощи фразы: "Дайте мне немного поработать!". Тут и барабан, и флаг, и некоторый инфантилизм с неадекватностью восприятия реальности.

Comment: Ну ассоциативное сопоставление тут, конечно, есть. Ибо суть пионерских символов та же, что и в армии. Но вряд ли пионеры могли дать  начало такому достаточно древнему выражению. В любом случае пионерская (скаутская) символика копировала армейскую, не наоборот.

Comment: Вот самое раннее (по поиску "флаг * рука"): "Дали указание ― я флаг в руки, барабан на шею и вперед заре навстречу! [Николай Дежнев. В концертном исполнении (1993)]" До этого момента - нет переносных значений, всегда описывается кто-то с флагом в руке. Всего 3 странички: [Ссылка](http://search2.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&mydocsize=&spd=&text=lexgramm&sort=gr_tagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&parent1=0&level1=0&lex1=%F4%EB%E0%E3&gramm1=&sem1=&sem-mod1=sem&sem-mod1=sem2&flags1=&m1=&parent2=0&level2=0&min2=1&max2=2&lex2=%F0%F3%EA%E0&gramm2=&sem2=&sem-mod2=sem&sem-mod2=sem2&flags2=&m2=&mode=main)

Comment: Корпус  шалит сейчас,  я не могу нормальный  поиск сделать "на расстоянии", а там же основная форма флаг тебе (ему и т. д.)  в руки". Но в 90-х уже не было пионеров. Мне выражение знакомо годов с 60-х, со школы. Но это явно не начало.   Надо смотреть в дореволюционных  источниках.

Comment: Посмотрите  пока тут. http://forum.lingvo.ru/actualthread.aspx?tid=75974

Comment: Там то же что и тут - датированная ссылка на 1992 год и "помню было в 70-х". Пионеры появились в 1922 году, чебурашка в 1969, а от возникновения выражения до фиксации в литературе проходят годы, так что ясно что выражение родом не из 90-х. Но и древность как-то не отыскивается. В корпусе самое старое нашлось от 1874, но без переносного смысла: "Впереди ехал бравый «чауш», с красным знаменем, вернее ― флагом, в руке;" [П. И. Огородников. Очерки Персии (1874)] Ну и если это действительно о пионерах, то 60-е как раз подходящее время для иронического взгляда на пионерское движение.

Comment: Ну как то самоочевидные версии... Наверняка в корне выражения лежит некая история, хотелось бы докопаться этой истории

Comment: @Бармалей Если это не литературная история (а похоже что так оно и есть), то найти ее истоки (и доказать что так оно и было, а не выдумано пост-фактум) очень проблематично. У нас уже получается что от появления до фиксации в литературе минимум 30 лет прошло.